# How to show html contents with a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, html, winforms, richtextbox

I want to show html contents in my form. I tried to it with rich text box.

```
rtBox.Text = body;
```

but it fails.

How to show html contents in RichTextBox? I am using VS 2008.

Comment: Do you want to show the highlighted html, or copy the rendered text from an html document?

Comment: I want to show text as we see in a browser..I don't want to use web browser.

Answer (score 6):

If you've got HTML content, you could use the [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control - otherwise you will have to convert the HTML to RTF to render in the RichTextBox

Answer (score 5):

Use a *hidden* WebBrowser Control and load it with the html content you want.
Then SelectAll() from the WebBrowser, Copy(), and Paste() into the richtextbox.

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser(); wb.Navigate("about:blank");
string url=@"http:\\....";
wb.Navigate(url);
private const int sleepTimeMiliseconds = 200;

while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
Thread.Sleep(sleepTimeMiliseconds);
Application.DoEvents();
}

wb.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
wb.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);
richtextbox.Paste();
```

Answer (score 2):

RTF encoding is different from HTML. You cannot do this straight away. Rowland has rightly suggested `WebBrowser` control.

If not, then you need to write your own HTML to RTF converter or find something similar.

Answer (score 2):

If you want HTMl highlighted text int he RichTextBox you can use something like [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/duncanharris/syntaxhighlightinrichtextboxp112012005050840am/syntaxhighlightinrichtextboxp1.aspx) (*Syntax Highlighting in Rich TextBox*).
From there you can make your own highlighting (based on the html elements).

Here's also an [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/htmlrichtextbox.aspx) (*An extended RichTextBox to save and load HTML lite files*)

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to spend money, the DevExpress RTF control can be given HTML.