# How to Paste text with images from clipboard like Microsoft Word do C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, text, copy, paste

i was wondering how can i paste the content of my clipboard like Microsoft word do, i mean for example if i want to copy something like:

```
Some text 
*some image*
More text
```

and paste it just like it was when i copied with the text and the image between the text, how can i do that?

I tried with Rich Textbox pasting with HTML Format but still got nothing... 
So far i can only paste the text without format or the HTML text with the tags also without format...

By the way, is there some way to override the Ctrl + V paste method of a textbox?

Thank you

EDIT: I'm working on WinForms

Comment: Where do you want to paste them to and for what purpose? Could you please explain more what your application is for.

Comment: Cause i'm programming a cooking recipe program, and my client wants to be able to copy&paste text with images just like he does on Microsoft Word.. I just need the same paste method that microsoft word uses..

Answer (score 0):

As to the first question, I don't believe you can do that with the RichTextBox. You can paste an image by itself, or you can paste just the text if you copied text and images from a website. But it won't paste both, unfortunately.

Here's a previous [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627991/c-sharp-how-to-show-html-contents-with-richtext-box-in-winforms) where some suggestions were thrown out.

---

As for the other question, if you want to override <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> functionality, you'll have to subscribe to the `KeyDown` and `KeyPress` events:

```
 private bool IsPressedCtrlV = false;

 private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
     // You have access to modifiers in here, so you can detect the Control key
     IsPressedCtrlV = (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V);
 }

 private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
     if (IsPressedCtrlV)
     {
         // When the key "press" is complete, handle ctrl-v however you want
         e.Handled = true;
         MessageBox.Show("No pasting allowed!");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the image displayed in RichTextBox via copy paste, then you can do the same from code as follow :

```
myRichTextBox.Rtf = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf);
```

simple step, set RichTextBox's Rtf property to value you get from Clipboard in Rtf format.