# how to use ContentAlignment.BottomRight

Tags: c#, text-alignment

I want to use `ContentAlignment.BottomRight` but I have a problem with it.

I have a textbox with multiline. I am doing a calculator. Whatever I want to enter as a value and result, I want to see on BottomRight part (as it is in Windows calculator). In the properties part of my textbox, I set multiline=true

`textbox.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomRight;` Gives the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.ContentAlignment' to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment'. 
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

but `textbox.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right;` works.But in this case there is no `BottomRight` option, only Left, Center, Right.

I have included the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Answer (score 0):

Text box does not support vertical alignments. It only supports horizontal alignments, which is why there is only a **Left**, **Center**, and **Right** option.

You might consider researching a RichTextBox, but I have not been able to find any alignment properties in code, despite what I have found on [the RichTextBox page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox_properties(v=vs.110).aspx). (I am inclined to say that I am wrong instead of Microsoftm, so keep researching.)

Something else you might consider is using a PictureBox or Label **if** you are only displaying text. [See a discussion on this topic on the MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/712d4df4-64e4-4748-8bff-6b9ed0db46fb/textbox-text-vertical-alignment).

One last thing to consider is looking into controls in which you can put html. This seems overkill to me, but you can find someone's question about it at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627991/how-to-show-html-contents-with-a-richtextbox).

Comment: But where is it used then ContentAlignment.BottomRight

Comment: @fasttruck5 **ContentAlignment** is not used in the **TextBox** class. It is used in other classes. For example, it is used in the **Label** class for alignment. You can research uses of **ContentAlignment** on [its MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.contentalignment(v=vs.110).aspx).